# Listの値が違う所でsplitをする方法

Tags: java, kotlin

**Listの値が違う所でsplitをする方法**
現在`List<Integer>`に
`{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}`
といった形で値が入っています。

これを 1 と 2 の間で、 2 と 3 の間それぞれで分割して、`List<List<Integer>>`と返すことは出来ないのでしょうか。。？

**ほしい結果**

```
{
[1, 1, 1],
[2, 2],
[3, 3, 3, 3]
}
```

言語はJava,Kotlinを使用しています。

Comment: コードを考える前にいくつか確認が必要なように思います(それらを確認するとおのずと必要なコードが思いつくこともあるかと思います)。例えばですが、1. 元のリストは数値順でソート済であると保証されますか？2. 数値が取りうる範囲は決まっていますか？(1～9までetc.)

Comment: 同じ結果を得るなら、「リストを分割する」のではなく、「リストにある数値をそれぞれ数え上げる」という考え方はどうでしょうか。数え上げた結果から、最終的にほしい`List<List<Integer>>`を作る方が簡単かもしれません。最初のリストがソートされている、もしくは同じ数値をまとめて良いことが条件ですが・・・

Comment: なるほど。。。
その後試行錯誤した結果自分は
```
val list = listOf(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
println(list.distinctBy { it }.map { List(list.count { e -> e == it }) { index -> it } })
```
こういう書き方で再現できました。。。
回答有り難うございます！

Answer (score 1):

特に工夫なくやれば、こんな感じですかね。

```
private List<List<Integer>> convert(List<Integer> originalList) {
    if (originalList == null) {
        return null;
    }
    List<List<Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer tmpNum = null;
    List<Integer> tmpList = null;
    for (Integer integer : originalList) {
        if (tmpNum == null || integer.compareTo(tmpNum) != 0) {
            tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
            newList.add(tmpList);
        }
        tmpList.add(integer);
        tmpNum = integer;
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。
自分が質問のあと試行錯誤した結果、出来るようになりました。
回答してくださった方法も頭に入れておきます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

splitという意味では正しくないですが、 `groupingBy 自分` でどうでしょうか。

```
    final List<Integer> nums = new Random().ints(10, 1, 4).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(nums); // [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3]

    final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> group = nums.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()));
    System.out.println(group.values()); // [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```